# Unable to build Shopizer project

Tags: java, spring, maven, shopizer

When I execute the `mvn install` inside the project `sm-core` of [Shopizer](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer), I am getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sm-core:
Could not resolve    dependencies for project 
com.shopizer:sm-core:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT: The following 
artifacts could not be resolved: com.shopizer:sm-core-model:
jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT, com.shopizer:sm-core-modules:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT: 
Failure to find com.shopizer:sm-core-model:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT 
in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was 
cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
reattempted until the update interval of 
org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates 
are forced -> [Help 1]
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The [Shopizer](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer) project is actually a [multi-module Maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). This means that it has a root `pom.xml` [of packaging `pom`](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/blob/2.0.3/pom.xml#L8) and [declares several `<modules>`](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/blob/2.0.3/pom.xml#L30-L35).

Those modules, which are Maven project themselves, are typically found as sub-folders under this root folder, which is the case here: there are 4 sub-folders, which are exactly the 4 Maven modules. To compile those sort of projects, you need to invoke Maven from the root project, in this case, `shopizer`.

You may ask why. In a multi-module Maven project, there is generally inter-dependencies: one module is dependent on another. In this case, the [`scm-core`](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/tree/2.0.3/sm-core) module that you're trying to build [has dependencies on both `sm-core-model` and `sm-core-modules`](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/blob/2.0.3/sm-core/pom.xml#L55-L67), which are two modules of that project. So when you're building it, Maven will try to look in your local repository those artifacts. The problem is that it won't find them: they have never been built before. Maven won't also find them on a public repository because we're dealing with SNAPSHOT dependencies. The solution is to start the build on the top project: Maven will order correctly the reactor so that when it builds `scm-core`, both those dependencies will have been built.

Put simply: in a multi-module Maven project, you should practically always invoke Maven commands from the root POM.

To solve your problem, you can check-out the [2.0.3 branch](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/tree/2.0.3) (which is the latest branch) and invoke `mvn clean install` on the root POM. I did just that successfully.

Comment: An answer WITH explanation. Rare these days, my thanks! @user1506424, I think that solved your original problem? I encourage you to click accept and ask new questions! :-)